# why the following javascript promise chaining not in sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

```
<script>
async function myDisplay() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    setTimeout(function() { alert(1) }, 10000);
  }).then(setTimeout(function() { alert(2) }, 5000))
  .then(setTimeout(function() { alert(3) }, 2000));
  
}

myDisplay();
</script>
```

I see promise chaining can make multiple asynchronous tasks to execute in sequence, so
I expect the output sequence is alert(1), alert(2), alert(3), but the actual output is alert(3), alert(2), alert(1), why?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not seeing any errors since you're not passing a function to `.then()`

Comment: @slebetman passing non-function to then is not an error. You might want to do, say `promise.then(undefined, errorHandler)` - no need for error there. Even if you do `promise.then(4).then(x => console.log(x))` that's allowed - the value printed would be the *previous* one from the promise chain, `.then(4)` is effectively skipped. I wouldn't recommend writing code to that effect as it's confusing but it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do promise chaining you need to return a new promise from the previous one. Like this:

```js
async function myDisplay() {
    new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() { resolve(1) }, 10000);
    })
    .then( result => { 
      console.log(result); 
      return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(2) }, 5000);
      }) 
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result); 
      return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(3) }, 2000);
      }) 
    })
    .then(result => { console.log(result); } )
}

myDisplay();
```

`setTimeout` just starts a timer that counts down from the moment it is created. So actually creating the promises beforehand causes them to trigger instantly if the timeout has already expired.

```js
const prom_1 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() { resolve(1) }, 10000);
});

const prom_2 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() { resolve(2) }, 5000);
});

const prom_3 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() { resolve(3) }, 2000);
});

prom_1
.then( result => { 
  console.log(result); 
  return prom_2;
})
.then(result => {
  console.log(result); 
  return prom_3;
})
.then(result => { console.log(result); } )
```

Comment: 1) "you need to return a new promise from the previous one", my example is not returning a new promise? in my example, promise.then() should return a new promise...

Comment: @user1169587 not an explicit promise. A `.then` turns whatever value you return from its callback into a promise. Just like async functions do (if you know about those).  Usually you would put in a callback function, that receives the result of the promise it resolved as argument, do something with it and return a value. Since you want to use timeouts you need to write an explicit Promise yourself.

Comment: The docs probably explain this better than I can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#chaining

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises, "which can be other asynchronous functions returning a promise. When that's the case, any callbacks added to promise2 get queued behind the promise returned by either successCallback or failureCallback.", is this ONLY this case, where inside then "is an asynchronous function returning a promise",  then following then() will wait the first then() finsih?
if inside the first then is a void return function, the second then() will not wait the first then()?

Comment: if inside the first then is a void return function (let said the void return finction named exportReport, inside exportReort is an asynchronous angular http.post, and then process the post response back, then return void), the second then() will not wait the first then()?

Comment: When you return no value from a then block, the next then block will run instantly with a value of undefined. When there is something like a http request you have to explicitly return a Promise (use the fetch API in case of http requests) and the next then block will wait for it to complete. Example when no value is returned: https://jsfiddle.net/qurapjL7/

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is it sets your first timeout, then when that first timeout is set, it returns the promise and then proceeds to set the next timeout, which has a shorter length, and so forth. Because the JavaScript engine is working fast, you're going to have a 10 second timeout, then a 5 second timeout, then a 2 second timeout. If you wanted the promise to wait those 10 seconds BEFORE setting the next 5 second timeout, you would need to add some code that would resolve your promise after 10 seconds, allowing it to move on to the next chained function.

Comment: 1) "when that first timeout is set, it returns the promise", what is the state of that promise? Fulfilled? 2)"If you wanted the promise to wait those 10 seconds BEFORE setting the next 5 second timeout, you would need to add some code that would resolve your promise after 10 seconds", how to do it?

Comment: @user1169587 "*what is the state of that promise? Fulfilled?*" it's Pending. And it will never change from that state because your code doesn't call `myResolve` or `myReject`, so the promise never settles.

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm not sure how you were able to write settimeout directly instead of a callback function, what I noticed is the promise is fulfilled immediately, so based on the timer inside the setTimeout, the order of alerts is executed.

check this article: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-wrap-settimeout-method-in-a-promise/#:~:text=We%20can%20wrap%20setTimeout%20in,This%20function%20returns%20a%20promise](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-wrap-settimeout-method-in-a-promise/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20wrap%20setTimeout%20in,This%20function%20returns%20a%20promise).

someone please clarify why settimeout is returning a promise or behaving as a promise

Comment: Already tried to clarify that in a comment on my answer. setTimeout is not returning a promise (it returns a reference to the timeout). But a value that is returned in a then block will be converted into a promise.

Comment: yeah, you are right any value that is returned is considered as the promise being resolved inside the then block.
my query is the settimeout is returning something immediately, not after the timer is completed, why is it so

Comment: The callback in setTimeout does not return a value, it only executes the callback code later. Note that setTimeout existed in JS well before Promises were introduced. Otherwise it would probably have been implemented as a Promise. That is why you have to wrap it in a Promise yourself.

Answer (score -1):

What you expected to happen would work this way, nesting instead of chaining:

```
setTimeout(
  () => {
    alert(1);
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        alert(2);
        setTimeout(
          () => {
            alert(3);
          },
          2000
        );
      },
      5000
    );
  },
  10000
);
```